# Link JQuery click methodto Button click event

Tags: asp.net

On my web page I have a button, and some JQuery code.  The problem is that when I click the button, the JQuery code is not executed.  Clicking the button still does a postback, and seems to ignore the JQuery code.
Here is my button:

```
<button id="btnCancel" class="button" runat="server" ><span>Cancel</span></button>
```

Here is my JQuery Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnCancel').click(function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

what I would like to achieve is that when the button is clicked, a message must be displayed showing "Hello".
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What people have said here will work. Make sure you have put all the pieces together.

Add jQuery

```
<head>
 ....
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Add your code

```
<button id="btnCancel" class="button" runat="server" ><span>Cancel</span></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>').click(function () {
             alert('hello');
             return false;
         });
     });
</script>
```

I added a "return false;" in there to keep the page from posting back, if you only wanted the javascript to run.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with script. Please check that you are loading jQuery correctly. Use any developer tool like firebug.

add JQuery like this in header.

Add jQuery file in your page like following where Scripts is folder and `jQuery.js` is jQuery file. If you already included this in your page then check with any developer tool that it is loading correctly.

```
<header>    
    <script src="Scripts/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</header>
<body>
   <button id="btnCancel" text="cancel"></button>
</body>
```

Or add jQuery from CDN

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Edit:
I think you need `vsdoc` file of your jQuery version. Please check following link it should work directly. If you want to download it then just copy and save it as `jquery-1.8.2-vsdoc.js` file.

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2-vsdoc.js
```

Comment: I added the JQuery to the head of the page, but will try placing it in a different file quick. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: If I create a new .js file under scripts, for example, myJQuery.js, what do I need to add to this file to get the intellisense working?  I am a bit lost here

Answer (score 0):

Since when the page rendered, the ids of the controls get changed to something else,I think you need to use

```
$('#<%=btnCancel.ClientID %>').click();
```

or

```
<button id="btnCancel" class='btnCancel' text="cancel"></button>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnCancel').click(function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: Even with the correct ID (to what it is changed after rendering) in the JQuery code, the JQuery stil does not get executed on the click event of the button